# What’s the subject and verb?

Tags: subjects

> During these sessions, the court could rule on major issues, this time around that includes the case about whether race should be a factor when colleges decide which students to accept.

For ‘this time around ... which student to accept’, what’s the subject and verb?

Comment: For the sentence as a whole, the subject is "that" and the verb is "includes".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Within the "when" clause, *colleges* is the subject, and *decide* is the verb.

Comment: But OP didn't ask about that little "when" clause at the end. He asked about *‘this time around ... which student to accept’*. Which IMHO ***is a sentence*** - it's just that OP has punctuated his example badly.

Comment: Yes, I can see that now. It wasn't clear to me when he asked.

Answer (score 5):

Grammatically speaking, the whole "sentence" looks a bit sloppy to me.

There's a straightforward sentence that should terminate with a full stop after *"issues"*. That's followed by *another sentence* which, stripped of the irrelevant extra words, would be...

> This time around ***those*** [major issues] **include** the case about [whatever it's about].

In short, the subject of the clause/sentence is *"that"* (but it should have been *"those"* anyway, because it refers back to *"major issues"*), and the verb is *"includes"* (but it should have been third-person-plural *"include"*).